# Limit memory allocation for process

Tags: memory-management, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2, and I would like to limit the allocated RAM memory space for a specific process, I have installed "Windows System Resource Manager" but I can only view the information, and not edit.

Is it even possible to limit the allocated RAM space for a specific process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a question for superuser.com, however, I believe that it wouldn't be common to control this in the OS-level but in the application/process level, e.g., in Java, we can configure our program/application server/etc to allocate a certain amount of RAM based on the arguments that we set on that particular JVM instance (`java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`), did you check if your application offers this kind of configuration? Did you check with the vendor? Perhaps some application-specific docs?

UPDATE:
Hmm, interesting, Czech this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit

Comment: The process is Tomcat, which does run on Java.
I limited the (java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m), but i still want to know if there is a way to limit it on the through the Windows also.

Comment: Hah, you got your answer then :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225682/passing-jvm-arguments-to-tomcat-when-running-as-a-service -- Once you find your Tomcat service within your Windows' regedit, you can add/edit these parameters: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024mb (assuming that you want to limit the RAM allocation to 1gb)

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see if that would be helpful.